# How to get sms/mms delivery report while sending through intent?

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to send sms from my android app using intent, i have checked out other links too to get the delivery report, but all of them are using SMS-Manager, but here I'm using intent and i am calling the device default sms app.

the code is like this:

```
Intent inten = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
inten.setType("text/*");    //for text
inten.putExtra("sms_body", body);
inten.putExtra("sms_body", body);
```

But if suppose the user doesn't have the sms balance, or the minimum balance required to send the sms, then obviously the sms won't be send, then how to

1> get the notification,

2> notify the user that his sms is not sent, and

3> the reason because of which it is not sent. (may be insufficient balance, or incorrect phone number, or any other possibilities)

basically i need to get the delivery report, is it possible to get that

and if I am sending the sms to multiple person then out of that list who got that sms, and who didn't

Thanks